# Quantization noise during writing wav file using C

Tags: c, file-io, wav

I'm just trying to write a library for read and write Wav files (just need it for audio processing), just as test, I read samples from a Wave File convert them to double (just standardize them to -1 ~ 1), and do nothing but transform them back to integer, according to the bit per sample (assume the Wav file have N bits per sample, I divided them through 2^(N-1)-1 and multiply with the same factor after to restore it)

But the problem is, I get a wav file with background noise (id say it seems like quantisization noise) and I don't know why, can you help me find it out?

the library is here: https://pastebin.com/mz5TWMPN
the header file is: https://pastebin.com/Lr2tbmnv

and a demo main function is like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "wavreader.h"

#define FRAMESIZE 512

int main()
{

    FILE *fh;
    FILE *fhWrite;
    struct WavHeader * header;
    struct WavHeader * newHeader;
    double frame[FRAMESIZE];
    int iBytesWritten;
    int i;
    char test;
    fh = fopen("D:/ArbeitsOrdner/advanced_pacev/AudioSample/spfg.wav", "rb+");
    if (fh == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open organ.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fhWrite = fopen("D:/ArbeitsOrdner/MyC/test_organ.wav", "wb+");
    if (fhWrite == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create test_organ.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    header = readWaveHeader(fh);
    printWaveHeader(header);

    newHeader = createWaveHeader(header->iChannels, header->iSampleRate, header->iBitsPerSample);
    WaveWriteHeader(fhWrite, newHeader);

    while (WaveReadFrame(fh, header, FRAMESIZE, frame) != -1)
    {
        iBytesWritten = WaveWriteFrame(fhWrite, newHeader, FRAMESIZE, frame);
        if (iBytesWritten < 0)
        {
            printf("Error occured while writing to new file\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }    

    WaveWriteHeader(fhWrite, newHeader);

    fclose(fhWrite);
    fclose(fh);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i divided them through 2^(N-1)-1` Division by a power of two (shift right) seems more natural  to me.

Comment: well, since c dont support directly the ^ function, left shift is the fastest way to do. but they both do the samething u know

Comment: Don't you loose some useful information when you divide then multiply your sample ? Can show these operations ?

Comment: in the ideal situation, as i have no extra operations on it, i wont lose any information, because the samples are discrate, they are only 2^N level, so it should be ok to standardize them, because u won't get some thing like 1.2/(2^(N-1)-1) since they are already discrate, thus multiply them back with the base should also be ok in this way. But in fact due to the system error (uncertenty) of floating point, yes there is a chance to lose informations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thx for viewing this post. I have found the problem myself, it is that, i used char instead of unsigned char for raw data (raw bytes). By converting them to int16 or int32, i haven't considered the sign bit. that means they are not exact the same value during convertion as it except to be.

the solution for this is:
either stay with signed char and use:

```
buffer[i] & 0xff
```

to get the correct raw data for convertion, or change the char types into unsigned char:

```
unsgiend char * buffer;
```